# scrollTop not working on window scroll in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to attached `onscroll` function to window. But when I use `scrollTop` to get the scroll position it is giving me undefined. Does `scrollTop` can be use with document element only ?

```
window.onscroll=function(){
  console.log(this.scrollTop)
}
```

**Working code**

```
window.onscroll=function(){
  console.log(this.scrollY)
}
```

Comment: http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `scrollTop` can only be used on scroll-able elements, like `document.documentElement.scrollTop` or `document.body.scrollTop` or a `textarea`, a `div`, ...

**All-browsers-compatible code**

```
window.onscroll=function(){
  console.log((document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop)
}
```

Found on [document.body.scrollTop vs document.documentElement.scrollTop](https://miketaylr.com/posts/2014/11/document-body-scrollTop.html)